# is VGA to HDMI cable is same as HDMI to VGA cable?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I want to use my TV with HDMI port as screen for my laptop with VGA port.i have searched over internet to know the price for the same.But every time when i search VGA to HDMI cable, it is showing results for HDMI to VGA.Does it make any difference?
if i buy HDMI to VGA, can i use it for my need?
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: If possible, make sure your computer doesn't have Displayport, as a displayport to HDMI adapter will be much better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because an active conversion is required between [HDMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI) (digital) and [VGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector) (analog), the direction *does* matter.

In theory you could probably create a converter that detects the direction automatically, though I doubt anyone will bother.

[Here’s an appropriate adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K4W62R4) that looks like it’ll do. It even supports audio.

Also, do *not* buy adapter cables without an active converter. They *cannot* work. They claim that “special outputs” will know what to do, but I have yet to see one. It’s essentially a fraud.

Comment: Just beat me to the answer. I had nothing different to say except to add this link to more mind-numbing detail on exactly what is required than most people would ever really need ;) http://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/hdmi-made-easy.html