# VGA to HDMI cable

Tags: hdmi, vga

I want to connect the HDMI socket on my newish laptop to the VGA socket on a pretty old monitor screen. I shan't want to bother with any audio. I've briefly looked but found reference only to DVI to HDMI. Is there a solution to this or is VGA obselete ?

Comment: Related: [is VGA to HDMI cable is same as HDMI to VGA cable?](https://superuser.com/questions/1168228/is-vga-to-hdmi-cable-is-same-as-hdmi-to-vga-cable?rq=1)

Comment: The title says "VGA to HDMI" but the question body describes "HDMI to VGA" here.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - Those are identical concepts......

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - (nevermind) I wasn't thinking.  Doesn't change the fact the question has been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

You need an "HDMI to VGA adapter". Use Google, or any search engine. I've found [this](https://www.amazon.it/Cavo-Adattatore-Convertitore-Universale-HDMI/dp/B007QT0NNW) on Amazon Italy, but sells from Germany. Description and technical details seems good.

Answer (score 0):

A plain converter cable (just wires with different plugs on each side) is not going to work because HDMI and VGA are totally different.

I have seen some specialty cables that came with a HDMI-only tablet or notebook that didn't work with other devices.
In that case the laptop or tablet has the converter already build-in in the device itself and it will switch some of the pins on the HDMI output to "VGA mode" when it detects the special cable.
Because this is a custom (not standardized) solution it only works with the specific combination of cable and device.

What you really need is a generic active HDMI to VGA converter.
These plugs or cables have some active circuitry (hence the name) inside the connector that generate the analog VGA signals out of the digital HDMI signal.
You can buy them from various vendors like StarTech, Hama, Evertech just to name a few.